# Custom Dashed Plot Lines in PGFPLots

Tags: pgfplots

I know that you can make a dashed line in pgfplots using the `\addplot[dashed]` option.  However, the line that produces isn't dashed the way I'd like.

I found `\pgfsetdash` in the documentation for PGF, but I can't figure out how to use it on just one `\addplot`.  If I include it anywhere within the tikzpicture environment, it changes all of the lines, including the axes.  I thought that adding a second `\pgfsetdash` would change the style, but it doesn't seem to have an effect.

Any advice for creating custom dash styles in PGF plots?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the key `dash pattern=<pattern>` to define a dash pattern in an `\addplot`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot [dash pattern=on 4pt off 1pt on 4pt off 4pt] {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```